# Add hover text without javascript like we hover on a user's reputation

Tags: html, hover

In stackoverflow, when we hover on a user's reputation we see a text. I have seen this at many places and the source code tells me that it can be done without js. And i tried and got only this-

```
 <div="text">hover me</div>
```

Answer (score 632, accepted):

Use the `title` attribute, for example:

```html
<div title="them's hoverin' words">hover me</div>
```

or:

```html
<span title="them's hoverin' words">hover me</span>
```

Comment: is it same like when we hover on reputation of a user

Comment: Yes, if you look at the source code for the reputation, you'll see that the title attribute is set to `reputation score`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this solution "not as good" as the JavaScript solution? I'm not claiming it is, but I'm curious what the JS solution is, and how it compares to yours, @Greg? By the way, thanks for your solution.

Comment: @Kevin This solution is in fact better than the JavaScript solution since it will work on browsers with JavaScript disabled, and it also adds a hint to screen readers about the contents of the element.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I would say that the only measure by which the JS solution would be better is in that you cannot style the text that appears and are left with the native implementation only.

Comment: Nice answer @gcochard. Say I would like to show 10 line of text hovering on a certain text. Using this method some of the lines are out of the hovering page. Is there any size attribute controlling that ?

Comment: MDN [mentions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) some accessibility concerns.

Comment: @David d C e Freitas: thank you for brightening StackOverflow with your edit to this answer ... don't know how to actually tag you but oh well

Comment: You might want to add, when you set a div/p/etc element it will show the hover text whenever you hover over any part of the element (more than just where the text shows) you might want to surround your text in a span element (the second example)

Answer (score 25):

The title attribute also works well with other html elements, for example a link...

```
<a title="hover text" ng-href="{{getUrl()}}"> download link
</a>
```

Answer (score 19):

Often i reach for the abbreviation html tag in this situation.

`<abbr title="Hover">Text</abbr>`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_abbr.asp

Comment: That element is specifically meant to be used to indicate abbreviations, so this is not a good idea. You're telling text-to-speech systems to pronounce it as an abbreviation. Use `<span>` if you just want a hover text.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for tooltip

For the basic tooltip, you want:

```
<div title="This is my tooltip">
```

For a fancier javascript version, you can look into:

http://www.designer-daily.com/jquery-prototype-mootool-tooltips-12632

The above link gives you 12 options for tooltips.

Answer (score 7):

This can also be done in CSS, for more customisability:

```css
.hoverable {
  position: relative;
}

.hoverable>.hoverable__tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.hoverable:hover>.hoverable__tooltip {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  background: #888;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverable">
  <span class="hoverable__main">Main text</span>
  <span class="hoverable__tooltip">Hover text</span>
</div>
```

(Obviously, styling can be improved)