# How to show full truncate text when hover with delay like youtube title?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I do this type of tool tip like youtube

Here is the image-

Click to see image

[image: 1]

I want to show same way to youtube. Pleas help me.

Comment: You can achieve this by using the [`title` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp).

Comment: Please research your inquiry before posting in accordance with [ask]. Duplicate of [Add hover text without javascript like we hover on a user's reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022843/add-hover-text-without-javascript-like-we-hover-on-a-users-reputation)